# How to print last two digits of given integer a=1234 in java

Tags: java

If i'm giving values like a=1234, i want to print last two digits 34 only.. can anyone give me solution for this...

```
int a=1234;
System.out.print(a);
```

Comment: Search for modulo operator.

Answer (score 27):

`number % 100` will result in last 2 digit

See

- [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/WVshAa)

Comment: Doesn't work for integers with a zero as the second to last digit, i. e. all years of the first decade of a new century like 1900 - 1909 will return only one digit. This is actually a bad solution if the original use case is to be considered. It will fail in 10% of cases. (Downvoted)

Comment: this get you close enough, you just need to pad another 0 if you have a digit

Answer (score 9):

User modulo 100

```
System.out.print(String.format("%02d", (abs(a)%100)));
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try this too

```
int a=1234;
System.out.print(String.valueOf(a).substring(2));
```

Out put

```
34
```

Comment: This only works for 4-digit integers.

Comment: @Johannes yes. this answer is only for the original question.

Answer (score 1):

**Assuming this use-case is for visual output only:**

Cast the integer to a string and get its last two characters.

```
int b = 1909;
String bStr = String.valueOf(b);
System.out.print(bStr.substring(bStr.length()-2));
```

This works only for integers with at least two digits though. So you might want to make sure you won't get a one-digit integer.

Also, feel free to use a constant instead of the magic number *2*.